# Is it possible to detect bad quotes in a poorly-formed JSON string and then parse the string as JSON properly?

Tags: json, parsing, ruby-on-rails-4, quote

I'm using Rails 4.2.3.  I'm parsing JSON sent by a third party (I'm not in control of how this JSON gets formed).  I noticed taht they are very occasionally sending poorly JSON, like so

```
    '{"DisplayName":""fat" Tony Elvis ","Time":null,"OverallRank":19,"AgeRank":4}'
```

Notice in the above, the word "fat", with the quotes, screws up the rest of the JSON.  In my Rails code, I parse the JSON, like so ...

```
    json_data = JSON.parse(content_str)
```

Although I can catch errors when JSON doesn't parse properly, I'm wondering if there's a way to account for these poorly placed quotes, correct them so that the above string does not constitute bad JSON, and then parse the JSON properly.

Comment: Of course you can try to correct the json, but what would you do with `{"a":","b":1"}`. You should not accept invalid json, because it is unsave and unpredictable and you can simply escape it. e.g. `\"fat\"` would be valid.

Comment: I would like to correct the malformed JSON (in the manner I have described above) if possible.  IF taht is not possible, then that's an answer as well.

Comment: You'd basically need to make your own Json fixer. Maybe split the string where you find `","` and other variations with spaces/new lines in between, then take everything after each `:`, take the first and last double-quote and finally replace every double-quote with a single, for example. Then you could use it in the parser. Another way would be to contact the Json provider and ask them kindly to provide a valid json.

Answer (score 2):

If you know exactly what malformations might occur, you might manage to do some crazy workarounds like using regex to match and correct the string before parsing it as json:

```
(?:")([^,:"]*"[^,:"]*"[^,:"]*)(?:")
```

http://regexr.com/3dpj1

But this is definitely something you shouldn't do if not absolutely necessary!! You better try to contact the source owner and make him escape the quotes correctly!

edit: Here is a full POC, where unescaped quotes are simply removed: https://jsfiddle.net/MattDiMu/y8khwfw6/

Comment: Thanks.  My knwoeldge of regular expression and Rails is still somewhat limited.  I see this expressioin identifies the bad quotes, but how do I use this to fix the situation?

Comment: @Mike - I've added a full POC in the original post.

Comment: Good deal.  As I'm using Rails to do this (as opposed to JS), how would this play out in RoR?

Comment: @Mike - Sorry, I'm currently no speaking rails. My answer wasn't inteded as full implemented solution anyway. I just wanted to show you how you could solve the problem. Basically it will be the same in ruby on rails anyway, just different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex you could check before parsing for double quotes `\"\"` followed by some word `\w+` and ending with `\"`. If you find it use `gsub` to replace the phrase with single quotes and a lookback `"\'\\1\'`.

```
t='{"DisplayName":""fat" Tony Elvis ","Time":null,"OverallRank":19,"AgeRank":4}'
t=t.gsub(/\"\"(\w+)\"/, '"\'\\1\'')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to make/have *some* assumptions about the "json" that are always true. If for example the json objects always have a fixed order of attributes, that could help very much, especially if only single attributes are problematic.

I would try to match

```
{"DisplayName":"(.*?)","Time":(null|"[^"]*"),"OverallRank":(\d+),"AgeRank":(\d+)}
```

and then replace with the help of some "fixer" function, that probably just uses the capture groups and re-encodes some ad-hoc created object back into actually valid json. One variation would be, to expand the `(.*?)` to only match when something is wrong.

However, the whole approach gets more complicated with optional attributes and even more so with a flexible order of attributes (all of which might still be manageable).

As you very well may have noticed, this only works if the assumption at the top is true. Depending on the assumptions you can make, the solution can be very simple. However, it all gets unwieldy, if these malformed Elements are completely irregular. So ... best of luck, I guess. Please post the assumptions about the json you believe to be true, if you need further assistance. If there are none however, a program would have to *guess*, what's actually meant. I mean, someone *could* mean:

```
{
 "DisplayName":"I want to have a quotationmark followed by Time, all quoted and 
               separated by a comma \",\"Time\":null, because that's how I roll
               and this entry shall not have a Time attribute...",
 "OverallRank":2, 
 "AgeRank":2
}
```

if the quotation marks get escaped in a wrong way, you'd get a problem. But as I said, you have to make *some* assumption about the "json". I mean, the usual assumption about json is, that it's valid, because otherwise it's just not json.

Answer (score 0):

Try handling error using begin rescue exception handling like,

```
begin 
 json_data = JSON.parse(content_str)
rescue =>e
 Rails.logger.debug e
end
```

This will raise exception when there is invalid JSON format and inform source owner to modify the JSON.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer will help me detect the types of quote malformations that I have described and further fix them.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy problem to solve.  Mostly because writing a JSON parser is non-trivial, and there I doubt you'd be able to adapt a parser to work the way you'd like.

If I absolutely had to solve this problem programmatically (as apposed to asking the vendor to fix their JSON) I'd probably do it with branching.

Taking your example JSON string:
`{"DisplayName":""fat" Tony Elvis ","Time":null,"OverallRank":19,"AgeRank":4}`

First break up the input into characters and iterate over them.  Every time a quote is encountered recurse and test both possibilities: the quote is part of the JSON, and the quote is part of the data.

Every time you find a quote you'll branch, so after two quotes there'll be four possible valid solutions, after four quotes there'll be 16 possible solutions, etc.

As you do this, stream each possible solution into a stream JSON parser ([like this one](http://www.lousymedia.com/json-stream/)) and watch for exceptions.  If one is thrown assume the possible solution doesn't work and throw it away.  I'd also throw away after a depth of 4 (or 8, if you expect double quoted strings in your data).  By limiting the depth you'll also stop solutions like `{"a\":\"b\", \"c"}` from being returned as valid.

Actually building this would take at the very least a few hours, probably a few days to do right, and there is still a good possibility it'll report false-positives.  It'll also be slow as a dog because you'll have to parse potentially thousands of different JSON streams using Ruby, instead of parsing one using a C JSON library.

You could alleviate some of the performance issues by appending all possible solutions to a queue and use a pool of worker threads to fetch potential solutions and work on them; but now we're talking maybe a week of work to clean up this data with a script.

Answer (score 0):

As far as bad quotes is concerned, this `regex_pattern` should be able to replace it with `\"`. Here's a sample Rails snippet:

```
regex_pattern = /(?<=[^\[{:,\\]|")"(?=[^:,\}\]])/
corrected_content_str = content_str.gsub(regex_pattern, '\\"')
```

This pattern has the following rules:

- A double quote should NOT have the following symbols BEFORE it: opening square bracket, opening curly brace, colon, comma, back-slash and a double quote. Hence, `(?<=[^\[{:,\\]|")`.
- A double quote should NOT have the following symbols AFTER it: colon, comma, closing curly brace, and closing square bracket. Hence, `(?=[^:,\}\]])`.

http://rubular.com/r/YBfcJYCf6D

This doesn't fix unpaired quotes, though.

Answer (score 0):

As the other posters have mentioned, if your service isn't providing you valid JSON, then there is no way to ensure you will be able to read the data they are sending you. What you can do however, is find some common cases and try and correct for these.

If your JSON documents follow the schema in your example, writing  a small parser will help you with trying to read malformed documents that adhere to it.

---

**Escape Double Quotes** -This will will back tick your unescaped double quotes, even if they are not balanced.

```ruby
invalid =  '{"DisplayName":""fat" Tony" Elvis","Time":null,"OverallRank":19,"AgeRank":4}'

# strip away { and }
tailhead = invalid[1..-2]

props = tailhead.split(/,(?=".+"\s*:)/)

pairs = props.map {|p| p.split(/:(?=(?:".*"|\d+|null|false|true)$)/i)}

escaped = pairs.map do |k,v|
    # is this a string property?
    string = v[/^"(.*?)"$/, 1]
    string ? [k, "\"#{string.gsub(/"/,'\\"')}\""] : [k,v]
end

valid = '{' + escaped.map {|p| p.join(':')}.join(',') + '}'

json_data = JSON.parse(valid)
```

Whenever you have a snippet like the above throw an exception, make sure all details are record in the log. As you collect more sample cases, you can improve your handling of them.

I'm no Rubyist, but I'm pretty sure you could do something with a begin rescue block where you would only need to call the above code with the ruby JSON parser flips out.